# Cocoa objective-c, is there an equivalent to PHP sessions?

Tags: cocoa, session, view

My app lets the user create multiple custom views by clicking a button (the views are simple circles). When they mouseDown on the circle I send a message to the NotificationCenter and run Core Animation to make the view pulse (fade in and out). I also set NSView *activeView to the view passed to the NotificationCenter.

In the background of these user created views is a custom view named gameMap. If a user clicks outside of one of the circles then gameMap sends a message to the NotificationCenter.

What should happen here is the activeView (circle) should move to the mouse click point. But because the NotificationCenter is in my AppController class, if it is being notified of a click outside of a circle view it doesn't have an activeView to reference.

I need a way to store, independent of classes, the activeView. In PHP I would just use a $_SESSION['activeView'] = $thisView, or something similar. Can I do something like this in cocoa?

Comment: Just define a global variable in a common file.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have been more clear, I was looking to avoid globals - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud. The Google led me to considering either an AppDelegate or Singleton, though I am unfamiliar with both and how to implement them and in essence they are (at least singletons) like globals and equally frowned upon. Blech.

Comment: Aside from needing a few paragraph breaks, the question is not that bad.  I think people are being way too harsh here with the downvotes.

Comment: @Brad - thanks I was surprised at the harshness but eh, no skin off my back, everyone has opinions, as for paragraphs - ug, writing the question late at night.